# Why won't this file write to the file system

Tags: python, ubuntu, io, python-2.6

I have a python script that fetches a file using `urllib2.urlopen`.  Essentially the flow is:

1. look for the file with `if-not-modified` header, if its been
   modified, do stuff to it and write a copy of it to the file system
2. if not, grab the copy local copy of the file that we stored on
   previous requests and do stuff to it
3. if there isn't a local copy *and* it wasn't modified, its
   the first time the script has run so we need to make the same
   request with no `if-not-modified` header and store that copy locally
   as well

The code for the last part is not working as expected.  see the code that handles the 3rd case below:

```
except IOError, e:
    #This is the first attempt to download the file.
    pathWithNoHeader = ROOT_PATH + uri 
    requestWithNoHeader = urllib2.Request(pathWithNoHeader)
    sourcefileWithNoHeader = urllib2.urlopen(requestWithNoHeader)
    document = ET.parse(sourcefileWithNoHeader)
    dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    statefile = open(os.path.join(dir, STATE_FILES) + uri, 'w+')
    statefile.write(sourcefileWithNoHeader.read())
    statefile.close()
```

This successfully fetches the file (i know because the other stuff i'm trying got do with the  info is succeeding) but writing the file to file system is failing with no errors.  essentially, the file is created but it is empty.  I'm new to Python (couple months) and I'm completely baffled by this. `statefile.write(sourcefileWithNoHeader.read())` seems like the culprit but the same sort of code works in other places just fine.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try: `sourcefileWithNoHeader.seek(0)` before `read()`ing it?

Comment: nope.  Let me try that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are first calling:

```
document = ET.parse(sourcefileWithNoHeader)
```

which if I'm not mistaken is a call to element-tree. This will already read the contents of the file, hence following reads will return the empty string. you can confirm this printing the result of:

```
sourcefileWithNoHeader.read()
```

before writing it.

To solve the issue simply save the contents into a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) before parsing it

```
contents = StringIO(sourcefileWithNoHeader.read())
ET.parse(contents)
statefile.write(contents.getvalue())
```